# Skype for business URI instead of Skype

Tags: javascript, uri, skype, lync, skype-for-business

As we have the option of opening links in skype by just providing the URI:

```
skype:xyz?call
```

Can we do something similar to achieve the same functionality but it opens in Skype for Business? Kindly let me know.

Cheers.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Found a solution for this after a lot of research.
Best alternative to work with Skype for Business:

```
sip:<xyz@domain.com>
```

This would open the chat window for the user and the user can do whatever they want from there.

Comment: this works for chat/IM. do you know an option to call?

Answer (score 14):

**Command-Line Parameters**

*tel:* |
Opens the Conversation window for an audio call but does not dial the specified number.

*callto:* | Opens the Conversation window for an audio call but does not dial the specified number.

*sip:* | Opens the Conversation window with the specified SIP Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) in the participant list.

*Sips:* | If Lync 2013 is configured to use the Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol, functions exactly like sip:. If TLS is not being used, displays a dialog box informing the user that a higher level of security is required.

*conf:* | If URI is self, instantiates the focus and brings up roster-only view. Otherwise, brings up roster view but does not send INVITE.

*im:* | Displays an instant messaging (IM)-only Conversation window with the SIP URI. Accepts multiple SIP URIs specified inside angle brackets (<>) without any separator.

**Exemple:**

Tel:+14255550101 | Opens a phone-only view with +14255550101.

Callto:tel:+14255550101 | Opens a phone-only view with +14255550101.

Callto:sip:kazuto@litwareinc.com | Opens a phone-only view with kazuto@litwareinc.com.

sip:kazuto@litwareinc.com | Opens a Conversation window with azuto@litwareinc.com.

conf:sip:https://meet.contoso.com/kazuto/7322994 | Opens a Conversation window and displays meeting audio join options.

**More information:**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398376(v=ocs.15).aspx

Comment: I am unable to understand your answer.

Comment: @Magellan How to also dial the number ? Any solution to it please ?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe useful for someone:   This is how to use skype for business to get to skype users via O365 (external communications to skype network needs to be specifically allowed)

```
<a href="sip:SKYPEALIAS@skypeids.net">Say hello</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can start a call or IM with Skype for Business, but you need to use the full URI, like

> im:sip:ID@company.com

if you just use the ID it will tell you that the contact does not exists, so this will not work:

> im:sip:ID

Best Regards from Argentina, Marianok

Answer (score 3):

If you use angular to dynamically call this try adding below to make sure it is not blocked

```
var app = angular.module( 'myApp', [] )
.config( [
    '$compileProvider',
    function( $compileProvider )
    {   
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);
        // Angular before v1.2 uses $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(...)
    }
]);
```

and then call

```
<a href="sip:SKYPEALIAS@skypeids.net">Say hello</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to make it working with `sip:` but it works with `sips:`

```
<a href="sips:xyz@domain.com">Open Skype Business</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skype-for-business-uris/sfbmobileuri?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Skype for Business Mobile URIs to initiate calls and chats using the
> Skype for Business mobile clients from websites and other apps.
>
> ### General Syntax
>
> ```
> "ms-sfb://" [operation] ["?" query ]
> ```
>
> ### Examples
>
> #### Start a chat
>
> ```
> "ms-sfb://chat?url=user%40contoso.com"
> "ms-sfb://chat?id=user@contoso.com"
> ```
>
> #### Start a call
>
> ```
> "ms-sfb://call?id=+1425-555-1234"
> "ms-sfb://call?id=user@contoso.com"
> ```
>
> #### Start a video call (Android only):
>
> ```
> "ms-sfb://call?id=user@contoso.com&video=true"
> ```

Comment: This looks like newer documentation. This wasn't there when the answer was posted by myself :). But thanks for sharing your answer.

Comment: If I use <a href="ms-sfb://call?id=+1425-555-1234">Call</a> it doesn't work for me. Any suggestions? The site tries to browse to this destination and doesn't find it (obviously).

Comment: this works only on mobile devices with the Skype app installed

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use lync15: instead of skype:

At least it opens Skype for Business... I'm still looking how to start chat - call - video call like for Skype Nothing in documentation, really annoying...

We are working on the same thing the same day :D

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work with lync15: unfortunately. It does try to open it but says that the contact does not exist.

Comment: Yup... Looks like lync15: is useless.
Guess it's just impossible to start chat / call like skype: uri with Skype for business.