# openUrl / URI to a Skype For Business account

Tags: android, html, ios, skype, skype-for-business

There have been questions about Skype For Business URIs ([Skype for business URI instead of Skype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542036/skype-for-business-uri-instead-of-skype)) but I can't find a solution that covers our business needs for both webpage links and iOS / Android openUrl / intent situations. (Note: this is not about normal skype URIs as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn745882.aspx).

I would like a public user with an unopened (normal) Skype desktop client or Skype app to be able to launch a chat to a reception of a business via a website or iOS link. That business has a 'Skype For Business' account, which as far as I can see doesn't have a Skype ID.

This didn't work for me:
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sip:reception@business.com"]];`
Nor:
`<a href="sip:reception@business.com">Chat</a>`

Is our only solution for the website to give instructions like:

1. Open Skype
2. Add contact
3. Search for reception@business.com
4. Then message us

Can a Skype For Business account be messaged without adding the contact first?

Answer (score 0):

I belive that is missing the 2-slashes for url schemes in iOS, try:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sip://reception@business.com"]]
```

I found your question because I was looking for the SilentPhone url scheme "sip://" or "silenphone://", that use the same as this Skype for Business

Comment: Appreciate the response, but this doesn't work for me. This didn't work on a mac or an iPhone that only has Skype. If the iPhone has S4B app, then it loads that app fine. But as the question says, I looking for a solution for end users with normal Skype.