# URI for skype to skype for business

Tags: javascript, uri, skype

I'd like to include a hyperlink that opens a chat with a Skype for Business account in normal Skype. This is possible for Skype normal to Skype normal or Skype for Business to Skype for Business, but I can't find a solution for Skype normal to Skype for Business.

This is similar to [openUrl / URI to a Skype For Business account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725656/openurl-uri-to-a-skype-for-business-account)

Using the normal URI scheme skype:[email]?chat won't work. It will create a new chat in Skype normal named after the email address but messages can't go through.
Adding the normal Skype user in Skype for Business will create a chat named alike (exactly the email address) which works.
However, even with that chat working, the URI scheme will always open a separate chat which doesn't work.

Ideally a chat window in Skype normal would open and messages could successfully be send to Skype for Business.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old, but just in case someone ever asks or has this question again. The reason that this is by design is because when you put skype:[email] in consumer skype the chat will go to Skype for Business because there is a backend federation between Skype consumer and Skype for Business.

A small caveat here, is the entity you are trying to contact must have enabled and allowed federation chat with Skype Consumer, otherwise the chat will be rejected.