# How can I use skype-uri.js with Skype for Business?

Tags: javascript, skype-for-business

I got the following code to create a button on my webpage to start a Skypecall:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
<div id="SkypeButton_Call_dhruv_1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Skype.ui({
          "name": "call",
          "element": "SkypeButton_Call_dhruv_1",
          "participants": ["echo123"],
          "imageSize": 32
        });
      </script>
</div>
</html>
```

Every time I click the button an error message appears which forwards to the skype download page. Error message:

[image]

I've installed the latest version of Skype for Business.

How do I get this to work with Skype for Business?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the Skype URIs don't work with the business version - it's really just a rebadged Lync.

Comment: In fact yep - here's the ones you should be using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542036/skype-for-business-uri-instead-of-skype

Comment: @JoeClay does that also work with call id's / phone numbers? Example: +410123456789

Comment: I solved this myself. See my answer bellow.

Comment: Nice one! Hopefully that answer will help anyone who runs into the same problem you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried some stuff. The best way would be what Joe Clay commented above. But I still got the problem that I couldn't make calls to classical phone numbers like `+0123456789`.

After some research I found out that I simply could use `tel:`.

```
<a href="tel:+0123456789">Call</a>
```

This makes Skype4Business to ask if you want to call the given number. Notice that Skype for Business must be your default application to deal with `tel:` links. You can change that by searching for "default programs" on your computer.

I hope this also helps some other people.