# Why does my "sip:" URI open a new email instead of opening a Skype for Business chat window?

Tags: skype-for-business

I'm trying to create a link on a web page that will open a new Skype for Business chat window, allowing a user to send me a message. I created a link with the format `href="sip:myname@example.com"`, as per [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542036/skype-for-business-uri-instead-of-skype). However, when I click the link, instead of opening a chat window, it opens an email! How can I correct this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of confusion, we realized this is actually the expected behavior if you click a `sip:` link containing **your own** Skype for Business ID. Since you can't start a chat with yourself, the link instead launches a window to compose an email. However, if you replace the ID with that of someone else (or have someone else click it), you will see the expected behavior!

This may seem obvious, but it wasted a fair bit of our time this morning, so hopefully it helps someone else.