# Is there a direct URI that will initiate a Skype for Business call

Tags: javascript

I'm integrating the Skype for Business app into an application we are developing for one of our projects.

Is there a URI that will initiate a direct call/video call with the intended recipient

The below code opens a chat window for IM

```
document.getElementById('skypeChat').href="im:<sip:"+textEmail+">";
```

Is there a similar one to initiate a call directly. I do not have the skype names of recipients but the official outlook email addresses

I had browsed through and found only code like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypeuris/skypeuritutorial_webpages)

But this is for regular Skype app I need for Skype for Business

I need the URI for Skype for Business  Call,Skype for video  Call,Skype File Sharing and Skype voice mail. Similar like one below for IM

```
document.getElementById('skypeChat').href="im:<sip:"+textEmail+">";
```

Any suggestions please

Comment: see if this works for you !! , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542036/skype-for-business-uri-instead-of-skype

Answer (score 0):

Use the skype for business web SDK. 
There are some examples for starting a video call over a jaavascript SDK.

See here for an URL-Example to start an audio call:

```
Post https://fe1.contoso.com:443//v1/applications/970/communication/startPhoneAudio HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer cwt=PHNhbWw6QXNzZXJ0aW9uIHhtbG5...uZm8
Host: fe1.contoso.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 210
{
  "operationId" : "74cb7404e0a247d5a2d4eb0376a47dbf",
  "phoneNumber" : "tel : +14255551234",
  "importance" : "Normal",
  "subject" : "SkypeforBusiness",
  "threadId" : "292e0aaef36c426a97757f43dda19d06",
  "to" : "sip : john@contoso.com"
}
```

https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/Resources-startPhoneAudio

The Example with the sdk is here:

https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk

I Hope this helps.