# JavaScript Hyper Link for Direct Call Skype for Business

Tags: javascript, skype-for-business

I'm integrating the Skype for Business app into an application we are developing for one of our projects.

Is there a URI that will initiate a direct call/video call with the intended recipient?

The below code opens a chat window for IM:

```
document.getElementById('skypeChat').href="im:<sip:"+textEmail+">";
```

Is there a similar one to initiate a call directly. I do not have the Skype names of recipients but the official outlook email addresses

I had browsed through and found only code like this 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypeuris/skypeuritutorial_webpages

But this is for regular Skype app. I need this for Skype for Business.

I need the URI for Skype for Business Call, Skype for video Call, Skype File Sharing and Skype voice mail.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/33553685/4882013

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skype for business URI instead of Skype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542036/skype-for-business-uri-instead-of-skype)

Comment: @ShivKumarBaghel You can use the flag link to flag duplicates; I'm not sure that I can tell if you did or not, just letting you know.