# Open Microsoft Teams chat from web application

Tags: web-applications, hyperlink, sip, microsoft-teams, skype-for-business

Is it possible to open chat window in Microsoft Teams app from a web page?
I am creating one web application that shows list of members in a team. When user double clicks on item in that list, it should open chat window in Microsoft Teams for the selected team member. 
For Skype for Business, there is [**sip**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542036/skype-for-business-uri-instead-of-skype) link format available which opens a chat window for the user. Is there any similar format available for Microsoft Teams? Thanks.

Comment: Please try out [deeplinking to a chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat) to open a chat window with the user in Microsoft Teams.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem with the [Deeplinking to chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat) option is that you are redirected to the teams website then prompted to launch MS Teams.

I have been able to solve that by utilizing a combonation Deeplinking and the MSTeams protocol. MSTeams protocol works like SIP would for Skype.

```
<a href="MSTeams:/l/chat/0/0?users=user1@domain.com,user2@domain.com">Teams Chat</a>
```

Now Teams launches without the redirect to the Microsoft website.