# Launching Skype for business via URI in Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: microsoft-edge, skype, skype-for-business, skype-uri.js

Managed to launch Skype for business on my website via the URI following the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542036/skype-for-business-uri-instead-of-skype)

```
sip:<xyz@domain.com>
```

Working fine on IE and Google Chrome, but it's not launching on Microsoft Edge 41 and there's no error in console too.

Anybody encountered similar issue before?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="sip:<xyz@domain.com>">Chat - Blockhead (new skypeFB)</a>
```

The above code works well on my side (using Microsoft Edge 41.16299.1004.0 and Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0 version, they all works), please try to [reset the Edge browser setting](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/reset-microsoft-edge-browser-to-default-settings-in-windows-10) or upgrade the Microsoft Edge browser version to the latest version.

Comment: It's weird that the same piece of code is working on IE and chrome, but just not Edge. Thinking if there's any policy set to Edge by the system admin..